# How to hide the status bar without affecting other screens?

Tags: flutter

I'm designing an app where there are several screens that will have a **status bar** with a special style. However, at the **splash screen**, which is the first screen of the app. I'm designing it to not have a status bar. But it also applies to all other screens even if they have status bars with uniquely designed styles, specifically the **Number screen** that I provide the code sample below.

> this is the status bar I mean

[image]

> **splash screen.**
> I use the code below to hide the **status bar**
> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:online_croceries/constants/assets.dart';
import 'package:online_croceries/data/sharedpref/constants/preferences.dart';
import 'package:online_croceries/utils/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(83, 177, 117, 1),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 350,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(Assets.iconLogo),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

@override
void initState() {
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
super.initState();
starTimer();
}

starTimer() {
var _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 2000);
return Timer(_duration, navigate);
}

navigate() async {
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

if (preferences.getBool(Preferences.is_logged_in) ?? false) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Routes.welcome);
} else {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Routes.welcome);
}
}
}
```

> **main screen**, I use it for root router

```
child: Observer(
    builder: (context) {
      return 
        
        MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          home: SplashScreen(),
          routes: Routes.routes,
          locale: Locale(_languageStore.locale),
          supportedLocales: _languageStore.supportedLanguages.map((e) => 
          Locale(e.locale!, e.code)).toList(),
          localizationsDelegates: [AppLocalizations.delegate]
          // home: APIUsing(),
          );
    },
    name: "global-observer",
  ),
```

> **NumberScreen**, for sign-in.  **TransparentAppBar** is a custom widget I use to create a status bar with a special style

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
int backDropBlur = 30;
return Scaffold(
    appBar: TransparentAppBar(
      transTitle: "",
      leadingIcon: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.chevron_left,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);

The above line of code is inside **SplashScreen's initState** function, you can easily see it in the code I provided above. It helps us to **turn off** the status bar, and this is something to watch out for. Once you've turned off the statusBar, **it won't show up again** whether you use it on another screen or not.

So in order for the next screens to have the status bar, the next screen right after the **SplashScreen** must turn the **status bar back on**. In my project, the next screen **SplashScreen** is **WelcomeScreen**. I turn it on with a simple line of code below, the place where I write the code below is the same as the line where I turn it off on the **SplashScreen**.

> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)

Or if you want a **neater way**, let the line of code that shows the status bar return right in the SplashScreen screen but instead of **initState()** it will be in the **dispose()** function,

Answer (score 0):

in my project, I use the following (use Brightness was obsolete)
Without AppBar:

```
return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
            //Set status bar icon color
            value: your_condition
                ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
                    statusBarColor: your_color,
                    //statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                  )
                : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
                    statusBarColor: your_color,
                    //statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
                  ),
            child: your_widget);
```

With AppBar:

```
return AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    systemOverlayStyle: your_condition ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
    backgroundColor: your_color,
);
```

You can use a combination of the two methods above to achieve your goal

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your instructions yet. Are you teaching me how to hide the app bar or something?

Comment: You can change color of status icon to match the color of status bar and match with color of page. How to change color you can see above and change it to achieve your purpose.

Comment: But where exactly should I put that line of code?